# To show blank in the 1st row (if it is NULL value) in BIRT Reports

Tags: eclipse, birt

I created a Report using BIRT Report Design in Eclipse Java EE IDE(Juno Release). In that Report, For the single row it have multiple values for the corresponding one column(I used LISTAGG() oracle function to map that).

(i.e.) Result column have multiple values in the below database table output :

### No    Name    Result     Mark

1     John    X            32
              XX
              XXX
2     Joe     X            56

```
          XX
          XX

          XXX
```

3    Andrew                34

```
          XXX
          XX

          XXXX
```

… It have both NULL and NOT NULL values in it.

"If the NULL values are in the middle means its showing the results properly in the Report"

Sample Result am getting in Report output for Joe (.pdf form)

### No    Name    Result     Mark

2     Joe     X           56

```
          XX
          XX

          XXX
```

Here the problem is, “If First record has a NULL means it is not showing properly in the Report, instead of that NOT NULL value will print in the front and so on…”

Sample Result am getting in Report output for Andrew (.pdf form)

### No    Name    Result     Mark

3    Andrew     XXX       34
                XX

```
            XXXX
```

But we have TWO NULL values present in the Front of Result column for Andrew (As you see sample database table output above)…

Is there any option to show blank in the first row(if it is a null column) for the particular row in the Birt report tool ?

Kindly Help me to Solve this issue… Thank you!

Comment: Using "visibility" property of report elements, we can hide fields with an expression evaluating if a specific column is null. Please clarify the question and let us know what you already tried.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the users other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199800/birt-report-tool